# Could not load file or assembly 'Sybase.AdoNet2.AseClient, exception in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

While running .NET code in my system, I'm getting the below exception:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Sybase.AdoNet2.AseClient, Version=2.155.8000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=95d94fac46c88e1e' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Comment: have you recently build your project and using the .exe file somewhere else?

Comment: no..I have recently copied the project from another machine.When i run the project i am getting this error.

Comment: You need to install the Sybase client.

Comment: You can now build the project on current machine or copy the project with latest dlls from bin folder in project

Answer (score 1):

In case of .Net Core I could solve the error by using a different approach to connect:

```
public MyContext() : base(new SybaseDataProvider("Core"), "You connection string here") { }
```

Before that I was trying to implement the `ILinqToDBSettings` file, but as I saw inside the code of `linq2db` there is a comment about that incompatibility:

[image]